# Marathon does not register with Mesos

Tags: ubuntu, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I'm trying to setup a cluster using Mesos Zookeeper and Marathon. I've done some initial setup following the docs in each website.

I'm using a virtual box which runs Ubuntu 16.0.4 to run the whole setup.

Now I'm starting the mesos master with the following command :

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

Next I start the mesos agent in the same virtualbox with the below command :

```
./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

When I navigate to `localhost:5050` , I can see that Mesos has started with an agent registered as well.

Now I ran Marathon with the below command :

```
./bin/start --master zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos --zk zk://localhost:2181/marathon
```

When I navigate to `localhost:8080` , I can find that Marathon is running. But it is not connected to Marathon yet. I searched thru some docs and found [this](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/authentication/) and did as it said.

But still I don't see Marathon in the Frameworks tab in Mesos dashboard.

If I try to start the basic Hello process in Marathon, it just goes to `Waiting` state. I found that this is due to Mesos not able to allocate resources for Marathon.

I have not done any other configuration except for running `make install` in Mesos dir so that it has created the `libmesos.so`. I have added that file's path as a environment variable with the name `MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY`

Please tell me if there is anything else that I need to do. I'm just trying out the cluster and am not setting it up for production yet.

**All the logs :**
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ja5g8zZjzdIW0uTH0htG

Comment: Can you provide Marathon logs? There should be information about what's wrong e.g. dropping offers due to invalid Mesos IP

Comment: You could try `LIBPROCESS_IP=127.0.0.1 ./bin/start --master zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos --zk zk://localhost:2181/marathon`. If that doesn't work, try using "real" ip addresses of the host, instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @janisz I couldn't paste the logs here due to size limit

Comment: @Tobi when I tried to run that command , it gave me this error `Scheduler driver bound to loopback interface! Cannot communicate with remote master(s). You might want to set 'LIBPROCESS_IP' environment variable to use a routable IP address.`

Comment: Can you find something similar to `Ignoring framework registered message because it was sent from 'master@127.0.1.1:5050' instead of the leading master 'master@127.0.0.1:5050'` in logs?

Comment: @janisz added some logs now

Comment: All I can find is this `[2017-01-09 18:19:41,131] INFO Elected` I think it is not connecting with 5050. Instead chooses the leader using zookeeper

Comment: Then just set the `LIBPROCESS_IP` to something routable, seemingly `10.0.2.15` from your logs

Comment: @Tobi Tried that. Still does not connect to Mesos.

Comment: What's in the Mesos Mater logs? Also, I think it'd make sense to also start the Master and the Agent(s) with a "real" ip

Comment: I started the mesos master, agent and marathon using the "real" ip. Still marathon does not connect. But the agent connects to the master.

Comment: Also in the Mesos dashboard, under Agents, I see one agent which is the one that I have started. But the CPU's column shows 0/1 . Does it mean anything ?

Comment: @Tobi I've added all the logs in the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Ja5g8zZjzdIW0uTH0htG

Comment: It looks like the Marathon is not registering with Mesos master. Modify your run script for Marathon- ./bin/start --master localhost:5050 --zk zk://localhost:2181/marathon --hostname localhost --webui_url localhost:8080 --logging_level debug